# Can I put a single quote in a user's password

Tags: ubuntu, quoting, password

I was wondering if there would be any issue with placing a single quote in a ubuntu user's password. We have a couple machines with a dummy user for automation purposes and I would like the password to be the same across all platforms (not the best for security I'm aware). Would a single quote be treated as a string literal even when setting a password or is setting a password treated as input for dev/tty and not stdin in this case so the escaping wouldn't occur?

Comment: @archemar provided the correct answer. I just needed a password for a new user on a ubuntu box. That password had to have a single quote in it. I just wanted someone to confirm my possible suspicions before screwing something up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there should be no problem in interactive mode (on the tty).

If you want to set it by script, you may need to escape it, or use other quote (e.g `"Pass'word"` or `'Pass"word'` ).